# Search settings: Indexing status stuck on 0%

Tags: search

When I click Re-index site, and confirm, I get a message that the index *will* be indexed but it never does.

Answer (score 2):

Run cron. (example.com/cron.php or go to Admin >> Reports >> Status and click "run cron")

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it via [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) to get around limit on the number of items that get indexed per cron run.

```
$ drush help search-index
Index the remaining search items without wiping the index.
```

and/or

```
$ drush help search-reindex
Force the search index to be rebuilt.

Options:
 --immediate                               Rebuild the index immediately, instead of waiting for cron.
```